# LWC Datatable - not showing related records

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, related-list

BELOW IN THE COMMENT I PUT FIXED AND WORKING CODE!

I try to build my own LWC Datatable component on Work Order object - which will show related Work Order Line Items records. The table is empty. How to retrieve the records into my LWC?

Here is my code:
woliDatatableDemo.html

```
 <template>
<lightning-card title="NEW Work Order Line Item" icon-name="custom:custom63">
        <div style="width: auto;">
                <lightning-datatable
                    key-field="Id"
                    data={data}
                    columns={columns}
                    ></lightning-datatable>
                 </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

woliDatatableDemo.js

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from "lwc";
import getWOLIs from '@salesforce/apex/woliControllerDatatable.getWOLIs';

const columns = [
    {
        label: 'Device', fieldName: 'AssetId'
    },

    { label: 'Serial No.', fieldName: 'Serial_No__c'},

    { label: 'Product', fieldName: 'PricebookEntryId'},

    { label: 'Quantity', fieldName: 'Quantity'},

    { label: 'List Price', fieldName: 'ListPrice'},

    { label: 'Discount', fieldName: 'Discount'},

    { label: 'Total Price', fieldName: 'TotalPrice'},
    
];

export default class WoliDatatableDemo extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @track data = [];
    @track columns = columns;
    
  
    @wire(getWOLIs, { woid: "$recordId" })
    
    wiredRecordsMethod({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
       let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        this.data = result.map(function(item) {
          return item;
        })
      this.error = undefined;
    } else if (error) {
      this.error = error;
      this.data = undefined;
    }
}
}
```

woliControllerDatatable.cls

```
public with sharing class woliControllerDatatable {

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<WorkOrderLineItem> getWOLIs(String woId) {
    return [
        SELECT Quantity, PricebookEntryId, Serial_No__c, TotalPrice, WorkOrder.WorkOrderNumber, Work_Order_No__c,
                 Duration, ListPrice, Discount, WorkOrderId, Parent_WOLI__c, AssetId
        FROM WorkOrderLineItem
        WHERE Parent_WOLI__c = false AND WorkOrderId = :woId
        WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
    ];}
```

Comment: is  your method returning any data? if so, is your 'result' variable getting a list of data? if so, is your 'data' variable getting a list of data? Are you getting any errors anywhere? what is being displayed and how does it differ from what you expect? This is troubleshooting 101. I image this question will get closed as being too broad.  You need to demonstrate what work you've done to try and find where exactly the problem is.

Comment: The table is available on the page, but the data is not showing, it is not fetching any records. I don't have any error messages, and because of that I don't know where is the problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to stringify nor parse the 'data', directly assign it`let result = data`.

Also, try `console.log(data)` and check in browser logs what is the data, do post the log to further solve the question

Answer (score 0):

fixed and working code:

```
export default class WoliDatatableDemo extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    columns = columns;
    @track data =[];

    //get related woliList from Apex class

    connectedCallback(){
        //calling apex method
        getWoliList({woid : this.recordId})
        .then( response => {
            this.data = response;
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log("error occured:"+err);
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@wire(getWOLIs, { woid: "$recordId" })` and `public static List<WorkOrderLineItem> getWOLIs(String woId)`. Here, the parameter you are passing is case sensitive, the WOID parameter should have same exact words. If you want to experiment try that, I personally think your wire otherwise is right